# Css style will not work in html site

Tags: html, css

I'am making my first site but my css style for links wont work can anybody help my please.

my code you can find out here: http://pastebin.com/eM8FzrWH

Comment: What does not work exactly? Your links should not be underlined with this CSS. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please place the code in your question itself and not somewhere: having it reduced as a minimal example is also very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style is working fine. You are removing the text decoration of a links, then re-adding the underline by wrapping the text in the links with

```
<u>Something</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are used  tag (which is for underline) within the  tag.
Remove  tag for your link tag. Now your css working fine.